# 'strftime' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, select, strftime, database-management

I am using Microsoft SQL Database Management Studio and it will not allow me to use the strftime() function to run a query. I have to create a table by months with new users and unsubscribers for each month.

This is what I had essentially which creates the error:

```
SELECT strftime('%m', createddate) AS 'Month', COUNT(createddate) AS 'Subscribers',
       COUNT(dateunsubscribed) AS 'UNsubscribers'
FROM subscriber
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

how else could I run this query without `strftime()` or how can I get `strftime()` to work?

Comment: That's because `strftime()` isn't a SQL Server function. Hint: Look at [formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead

Answer (score 3):

`strftime` is a [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) function, and isn't available in Microsoft's [[image]sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server).

For this simple usecase (extracting a month from a date), you could user [`month`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT   MONTH(createddate) AS [Month], 
         COUNT(createddate) AS [Subscribers],
         COUNT(dateunsubscribed) AS [UNsubscribers]
FROM     subscriber
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

**EDIT:**
To address the question in the comment, the `group by` clause doesn't take an ordinal like the `order by` clause does. You'll need to specify the expression you want to group by:

```
SELECT   MONTH(createddate) AS [Month], 
         COUNT(createddate) AS [Subscribers],
         COUNT(dateunsubscribed) AS [UNsubscribers]
FROM     subscriber
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY MONTH(createddate);
```

Comment: I keep receiving this error now: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: @Klew that's a different issue. See my updated answer for a solution.