# strftime is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the work of hours my employee's has done.
the system works like this :
When there's a login the timestamp write itself in a database and the same when I logout.
now I try to calculate the work of hours and I get an error saying "Strftime is not a recognize built in function.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\PROJECT\TEAM5\TEAM5\TEAM5 PROJECT\DATABASE\STOREMANGE.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
string sql = "SELECT Username  ,logdate as 'Date' , MIN(logtime) as 'IN' , MAX(logtime) as 'OUT', " +
        " CAST(((strftime('%s', max(logtime)) - strftime('%s', min(logtime))) % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60) AS TEXT) || ':' || " +
        " CAST((((strftime('%s', max(logtime)) - strftime('%s', min(logtime))) % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60)) / 60 AS TEXT) as 'HOURS - HH:MM'  " +
        " FROM Work_card  group by Username , logdate order by logdate";
```

All I'm looking for it to calculate the hours and it seems like with the strftime it't not working.
appreciate any kind of help, thank you !

Comment: All references I can find to `strftime` point to it being a PHP function, not a SQL Server function. I've also found reference to it being an SQLite function.

Comment: do you know of an SQL function that can do what I'm trying to ??

Comment: The duplicate that Lasse found seems to cover an alternative.

Comment: Is it just me or I cannot see the answer by Lasse ?

Comment: You might need to refresh the page. Otherwise you can get to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845237/strftime-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name)

Comment: uh I see it now, but it still doesn't tell me how I can calculate the hours :(

Comment: Ask another question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a query that is not generated dynamically.